# Ajax request within an ExtJS preprocessor

Tags: extjs, preprocessor, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I created a preprocessor (registered via Ext.Class.registerPreprocessor), and for certain kind of classes it will create an ajax request. Depending on the result of this ajax request, the class will be altered or not.

Class Init -> Preprocessor 1 -> My Preprocessor -> Ajax Request Query + Response -> Preprocessor 2 -> Class Instancied

It would be easy if I was able to call the "next" preprocessor by myself, but I don't know if I can do that. I tried a few things, but whatever I do the next preprocessor is called automatically, and I have no control on the final instance.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to actually make the AJAX request synchronous (quite shocking, isn't it), by using async: false.